# Moving around a grid with directions ( left / right )

Tags: javascript, loops

[image]

"Create a function named blocksAway that will receive an array of directions, and return an object that calculates how far north and east those directions will take someone."

The function will be tested in a manner like so

```
console.log(blocksAway(["right", 2, "left", 3, "left", 1]));
```

How can I move through a grid using directional input like in the code above? The blue dot will always start in the bottom left corner. In the example above, the answer would be

```
{east  : 1, north : 3}
```

Thanks for the help, I'm not sure how to word this any better I don't know where to start, thanks!

Comment: If the blue dot starts in the bottom left corner, then won't you "fall off" the grid if you move right twice and then left 4 times? How do you get `north: 3` if you never move "up"?

Comment: @Nick Parsons I think ndanvers meant `"up", 3` instead of `"left", 3`

Comment: Do you want a way to make the function or a way to  implement it on the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a simpler way but this works:
(Answer for the function)

```js
function blocksAway(arr) {
  var output = {north: 0, east: 0};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    if (arr[i] === "up") output.north += arr[i + 1];
    if (arr[i] === "down") output.north -= arr[i + 1];
    if (arr[i] === "left") output.east -= arr[i + 1];
    if (arr[i] === "right") output.east += arr[i + 1];
  }
  return output;
}

var o = blocksAway(["right", 2, "up", 3, "left", 1]);

console.log(o);
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the post, it certainly gives me ideas. each output is dependant on the previous directions. So in the case of the picture and original post, ```console.log(blocksAway(["right", 2, "left", 3, "left", 1]));``` would move the blue dot 2 spaces to the right, and "left 3" would move to the left of the previous direction, being "up"wards